How to use NOT LIKE in SQL with a string of words
I am having trouble excluding text in a field that starts with "Community Launch".  I am using the code:
rp.project_name NOT LIKE 'Community Launch%'

but this is removing any text that also has Community in it.  I need for it to remove text that starts with Community Launch.
I have tried different variations and searched, but I am unable to resolve.

try: SELECT *
FROM your_table rp
WHERE rp.project_name NOT LIKE 'Community Launch%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(rp.project_name)) = rp.project_name

The condition actually looks OK. Can you share some sample data and the expected vs actual result you're getting?

NOT LIKE should of course work too. However, I can't see why your query doesn't work as expected. Provide a [mcve], showing the problem. And a prepared https://dbfiddle.uk/ would be great.

@ErgestBasha Why shouldn't they use NOT LIKE?

@JonasMetzler it doesn't use an index if present, at least in MySQL as far as I know, even left doesn't use it if I'm not mistaken. I should previously mentioned

Either way we cannot reproduce this https://dbfiddle.uk/1MKOIcuQ please give a [mcve]

@Charlieface I did a live test on one of my live server and I can confirm from the explain plan that NEITHER not like ,LEFT or SUBSTRING didn't use an index. It seems that maybe the fastest way would be select the primary key using rp.project_name LIKE 'Community Launch%' and excluding it using exists or in clause. I do not know if this is the same behavior on SQL Server.  Although I was wrong on substring, I did remembered wrong that it uses the index. Note I tested on a live table

Hello Everyone.  I have found the issue. The logic was working as expected, it was a different set of logic which was not working as intended, thus giving me the incorrect values.  Thank you all for your help and time!
